# Is there any concept of implicit JOIN in SQL UPDATE?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am exploring the SQL UPDATE statement.

Are both the following update statements effectively the same?

```
UPDATE TBLNAME
SET COL=C.COLX
FROM ANOTHERTBL AS C
WHERE C.CUSTID=TBLNAME.CUSTID 

UPDATE T
SET T.COL=C.COLX
FROM TBLNAME T
JOIN ANOTHERTBL AS C
ON C.CUSTID=T.CUSTID
```

In the 1st UPDATE, is the JOIN implicit?

Comment: The two are exactly equivalent.

Comment: The explains will probably be identical.  The second is considered a "better" way to write the sql, as it allows you to separate join criteria from filter criteria, it's easier to read as you add more tables, and it's easier to convert to an outer join if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

The constructs are functionally the same. Below is from the the [UPDATE documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql).

> If the object being updated is the same as the object in the FROM
> clause and there is only one reference to the object in the FROM
> clause, an object alias may or may not be specified. If the object
> being updated appears more than one time in the FROM clause, one, and
> only one, reference to the object must not specify a table alias. All
> other references to the object in the FROM clause must include an
> object alias.